# different json structure returned for the same call depending on endpoint

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I created a ticket with SoftLayer support and for some reason they suggested I post here , so here it is. I am using the python client to call the API method list_vlans().

This call returns a different json structure depending on the Softlayer location I am in which cant be correct. (This breaks all of my automation) Specifically when I am on a virtual server in Dallas, I am getting back a response structure that is completely different that when I am in DC or Frankfurt for example.

This makes no sense and I am using the same very simple code defined here:

http://softlayer-api-python-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/managers/network/

Comment: to give an example in dallas I see this  : "virtualGuestCount": 8,   and in DC this key does not exist and is a list of virtual server metadata "virtualGuests": []?? Also the key  "subnets" does not exist in Dallas and does elsewhere...

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with my code and I see that I did not realize when I spun up these new virtual servers the version of the SoftLayer python client is different. (SoftLayer (5.0.0)) Somehow I got 4.1.1 when I starting building out softlayer locations. Once I install the old version everything works fine..  To be clear its not that it did not work its that the response is different. What I got with the old method was a way to get all information (subnet and vlan) in a single call which looks like is not possible with the new version.

Comment: What I can see is that the object masks used in the version 5.0.0 are differnt from the version 4.1.1 , I f am not wrong there were issued with those object masks when you have a lot VLAN, basically the method failed because of the large amount of data, I think you can use the version 4.1.1 or use "API calls" using the object mask that you need.